# using IBM.WMQ not working and other of its features

Tags: .net, ibm-mq

I have been trying to put and get a message in an out of a IBM MQ while using the C# code in the [IBM website](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=programs-example-c-code-fragment-use-net) im not able to run the program i have tried all the possible error corrections but was not able to figure it out. and even the MQ Explorer is working well there is a Message Queue already but .net is not responding

I have tried configuring the files in .net but it was not useful.
i was expecting to out and get a message to and from a message queue

**//New Update**

I was able to add the reference and the program is compiling and giving some warnings and an error saying:

**error Message:**
Visual Studio cannot start debugging because the debug
target 'CUsers SShashan\documentslvisual studio
2015 Projects\MQtestMQtest bin\DebugMQtest.dll"' is
missing. Please build the project and retry, or set the
OutputPath and AssemblyName properties appropriately to
point at the correct location for the target assembly.

File name:
MQtest

**Warning message:**
The primary reference "amqmdnet, Version =9.2.4.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=dd3cb1c9aae9ec97, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could
not be resolved because it was built against the
"NETFramework.Version=v4.6.2" framework. This is a higher version than
currently targeted framework "NETFramework, Version =v4.5.2".

**Code From:**
code i used is from [Here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.0?topic=programs-example-c-code-fragment-use-net)

details:

Queue manage name

QM1, QM2

host -- 127.0.0.1

channel -- QM1toQM2

ports -- sender:1414 listner:1415

Queue: QM1toQ2 (Q2 is QM2s queue)

**//Update end**

Can you help me with this please.

Thanks.

Comment: What error did you receive from your C# application?  Did any error show up on the queue manager logs at the same time? If it did please provide this as well.  Please do not try to post errors in comments,  instead edit and update your question with the new details. How do you expect to get advice without providing any details of the problem you have?

Comment: It is worth posting your application code as well.

Comment: I have added the error image. and the application code is same as in the ibm website link that i have added.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to configure the IBM MQ files in .net Before starting to run the program.

Comment: Do you have the MQ Client installed? This can be either the full client or the redist client.   If you want to switch to managed mode you only need the one dll out of the install (amqmdnet.dll if less than  MQ 9.2 or at MQ 9.2 for framework, or amqmdnetstd.dll in 9.2 for core).

Comment: Note it is also good to post the text of the error in you question rather than a image because a search can't index the error message that you have in the image.

Comment: Actually i installed MQ dev 9.2.4 amqmdnet.dell is present in the directory. I'm trying this ibm mq for the first time so i didn't know how to configure the system before executing. Being a beginner is there any site that tells the detailed steps for put and get a message from queue using c#

Comment: Take a look at the sample at https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns/tree/master/dotnet  It comes with a vscode project package, so the environment will be set correctly for you.

Comment: Did you add the `amqmdnet.dll` as a reference library to your project?  Because in the error message screen-shot, the "**_using IBM.WMQ_**" has a red underline which usually means that VS does not know about the package.  i.e. Missing reference.

Comment: No i havent added dll file as a reference, do i need to add a config file for this project like creating a asp web application or just the console will do the job.

Comment: The error in your question is just telling you that your build failed. In your screen shot I can see to compile failures in your Output window. You must correct these errors before your program will build. Please could you copy the text of these errors in full and put them in your question. We can only see a portion of the errors in your screenshot.

Comment: @MoragHughson-- It showed me many error so i have attached the error screenshots.. Thanks

Comment: Wh6 don't you copy and paste the text of the errors as has been requested multiple times. You should follow Roger's suggestion. Chughts also provide another IBM example which you can try that that will set up the env for you to compile, have you tried that.